# How can I check whether a NSManagedObject already exist in coredata by my primary key?

Tags: object, core-data, exists

I use this method,but not correct.

```
- (BOOL)checkExistByEntityName:(NSString *)entityName primaryKeyName:(NSString *)keyName primaryKey:(NSNumber *)primaryKey
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@==%@", keyName, primaryKey];

    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    [request release];

     if (count > 0) {
          return YES;
    } else {
          return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Predicate programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795) is your friend.

> The format string supports printf-style format arguments such as %x
>   (see “Formatting String Objects”). Two important arguments are %@ and
>   %K.
>
> - `%@` is a var arg substitution for an object value—often a string,
>     number, or date.
> - %K is a var arg substitution for a key path. When
>     string variables are substituted into a format string using `%@` , they
>     are surrounded by quotation marks. If you want to specify a dynamic
>     property name, use `%K` in the format string, as shown in the following
>     example.

```
NSString *attributeName = @"firstName";
NSString *attributeValue = @"Adam";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",
        attributeName, attributeValue];
```

So, just use

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", keyName, primaryKey];
```

Hope that helps.